# XML Parsing Errors

Tags: layout, xml, configuration, simplexml, construct

I believe I have a syntax error or something? I'm confident it's either something to do with xml or syntax. Everything appears to be in order when i look into the file. This error is dealing with the mage notification module, correct? The problem is i don't see any broken code such as: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

```
2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Space required after the Public Identifier  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                  ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : SystemLiteral &quot; or ' expected  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                  ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                  ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 7 and body  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():        ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 4 and html  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 2  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Space required after the Public Identifier  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                  ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : SystemLiteral &quot; or ' expected  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                  ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                  ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 7 and body  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():        ^  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 4 and html  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 2  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
    2017-11-16T23:12:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Space required after the Public Identifier  in /var/www/code/www.oop.com/releases/20171116222810/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Magenotification.php on line 126
```

This is line 126 in Magenotification.php

```
   try {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        }
```

Doesn't help me out at all.

Magenotification.php

```
class Magestore_Magenotification_Model_Magenotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const XML_FREQUENCY_PATH    = 'magenotification/general/frequency';
    const XML_LAST_UPDATE_PATH  = 'magenotification/general/last_update';
    const XML_MAGESTORE_URL_PATH  = 'magenotification/general/magestore_url';

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('magenotification/magenotification');
    }   

    public function checkUpdate()
    {
        $timestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());

        if (($this->getFrequency() + $this->getLastUpdate()) > $timestamp) 
        {
            return $this;
        }

        $notificationXml = $this->getNotificationData();
        $noticeData = array();
        if ($notificationXml && $notificationXml->item) 
        {
            foreach ($notificationXml->item as $item) {
                    $item_data = array(
                        'severity'      => (int)$item->severity,
                        'date_added'    => $this->getDate((string)$item->date_added),
                        'title'         => (string)$item->title,
                        'description'   => (string)$item->description,
                        'url'           => (string)$item->url,
                        'added_date'    => $this->getDate((string)$item->date_added),
                        'related_extensions' => strtolower($item->related_extensions)
                    );

                    if($this->allowGetFeed($item_data)){
                        $noticeData[] = $item_data;
                    }
            }
            if($noticeData) 
            {
                $this->parse(array_reverse($noticeData));

                $this->setLastUpdate();
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }   

    public function allowGetFeed($item)
    {   
        if($item['related_extensions'] == null || $item['related_extensions'] == '0'){
            return true;
        }

        $modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();
        foreach ($modules as $moduleName => $moduleInfo) {
            if ($moduleName==='Mage_Adminhtml') {
                continue;
            }
            if ($moduleName==='Magestore_Magenotification') {
                continue;
            }           
            if(strpos('a'.$moduleName,'Magestore') == 0){
                continue;
            }
            $extension_code = str_replace('Magestore_','',$moduleName);
            $related_extensions  = explode(',',$item['related_extensions']);
            if(count($related_extensions)){
                foreach($related_extensions as $related_extension){
                    if(strtolower($related_extension) == strtolower($extension_code)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getLastUpdate()
    {
        $timestring = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_LAST_UPDATE_PATH);
        return strtotime($timestring);
    }

    public function setLastUpdate()
    {
        $config = Mage::getModel('core/config');
        $timestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()); 

        $config ->saveConfig(self::XML_LAST_UPDATE_PATH,$timestamp);
        $config->cleanCache();
    }   

    public function getFrequency()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_FREQUENCY_PATH) * 3600;
    }

    public function getMagestoreUrl()
    {
        $lastTimeNotice = strtotime($this->getLastNotice()->getAddedDate());
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_MAGESTORE_URL_PATH) .'/magenotification/service/getfeed3/lastupdatetime/'. $lastTimeNotice;
    }

    public function getNotificationData()
    {   
        $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
        $curl->setConfig(array(
            'timeout'   => 2
        ));
        $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $this->getMagestoreUrl(), '1.0');
        $data = $curl->read();

        if ($data === false) {
            return false;
        }
        $data = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $data, 2);
        $data = trim($data[1]);
        $curl->close();

        try {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        return $xml;
    }

    public function getNotificationXml()
    {
        try {
            $data = $this->getNotificationData();
            $xml  = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $xml  = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>');
        }

        return $xml;
    }

    public function getDate($rssDate)
    {
        return gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($rssDate));
    }   

    public function parse($data)
    {
        if(count($data))
        {
            try{
                foreach($data as $item)
                {
                    if(!$this->is_existedUrl($item['url']) )
                    {
                        $this->setData($item)->save();
                        $this->setId(null);
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function is_existedUrl($url)
    {
        $collection = $this->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('url',(string)$url);         
        if($collection->getSize())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public function getLastNotice()
    {
        $item = $this->getCollection()
                        ->setOrder('added_date','DESC')
                        ->getFirstItem();
        return $item;
    }
}
```

**Found**
The document has moved here.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at www.magestore.com Port 80
String could not be parsed as XML

**Found**
The document has moved here.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at www.magestore.com Port 80
String could not be parsed as XML

When I click on here it brings up some xml and the message below, i guess it means there is something wrong with channel tag:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<channel/>
```

Comment: Can you share the whole of `Magenotification.php` ?

Comment: @LukeRodgers, it's up there now. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that may come across this, a 'quick' fix is below:

Update this line:

```
$curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $this->getMagestoreUrl(), '1.0');
```

To:

```
$curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, 'https://www.magestore.com/service/notification.xml', '1.0');
```

It seems that Magestore have changed their notification URL, so the update above should fix.

I do believe updating the extension Magestore_Magenotification to the latest version is the reccomended fix. However, this will do if you are looking to stop the system.log being full of this error.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, something is wrong with the XML file it is trying to parse.

Could you change the following code:

```
try {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```

to:

```
try {
   $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $data . "\n";
   echo $e->getMessage();

   return false;
}
```

And post the results here? It should print out the XML data it is trying to parse and it's error message, I'm sure it shows something helpful.

Comment: it's been added above.

Answer (score 2):

I saw that 3 notified for you.

1. > `&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;`
2. > This XML file does not appear to have any style information
   >   associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
  3.

> ```
> $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
>         $curl->setConfig(array(
>              'timeout'   => 2
>         ));
>         $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $this->getMagestoreUrl(), '1.0');
>         $data = $curl->read();
> ```

That means your Url return **HTML** string instead of **XML** string can you debug that and print the **HTML** response, I think your controller was wrong not **SimpleXMLElement**

**Updated**

Let me explain more

```
$curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
        $curl->setConfig(array(
            'timeout'   => 2
        ));
        $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $this->getMagestoreUrl(), '1.0');
        $data = $curl->read();
```

**$this->getMagestoreUrl()**  <== This is your url request (show it)..

**$data = $curl->read();** this is your response text of the controller (var_dump or print_r) this data.

Comment: Add this into the Magenotification.php file and see what it displays? @HoangHieu

Comment: Nope!. that notice to you. what problem is your response of the **$this->getMagestoreUrl()** URL when you had been gotten a request by using CURL, please check that HTML response.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the code you provided. Please explain more.

Comment: Check update answer.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, the code you gave me throws errors.

Comment: I not give you a code, i give you how to debug your code, the problems is in your response text of the controller.